# How to fix "Data can not be found' error in Python when trying to connect to API

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pull data from an API and I am getting an error. It states that the state codes in URLs should be lower case. I am not sure how to fix that when that is a part of the API and I have combed through it and the problem doesn't seem to jump out at me.

The API I am trying to connect to is :
https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/us/daily.json

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use this url.

```py
url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/v1/us/daily.json"
```